# Microsoft Edge not closing normally, need to end task every time

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-edge

I am facing a strange issue with Microsoft edge. It's not closing with the "x" button. Every time I have to go to the task manager to Endtask and close it. Looked over the internet, but no help.

Even modifying and reinstalling the same in the Apps list not helping. What might be the issue? I have no pending updates.

Comment: Does it happen in InPrivate mode?

Comment: @harrymc no. It happens everytime I open edge. Just can't close it normally. Have to force shut it down in task manager

Comment: If this also happens in InPrivate mode, try to reinstall Edge [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/edge?displaytou=1&brand=M024&OCID=GT6732). If it still happens, boot in Safe mode. If it also happens in this mode, try [Repair Install](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

Comment: Since this does not happen in InPrivate mode, disable ALL extensions, and see if that makes a difference. Reinstalling Windows to fix a problem with Edge is an overkill solution. There is a faster solution than performing a fresh install of Windows, delete the entire user profile for Edge, that is a near guaranteed solution to this problem (but that also is an overkill solution).

Comment: @Ramhound I have uninstalled all extensions and repaired Edge. Tried all ways. Just not working. Reinstalling windows is an overkill solution that's why I am trying to delay it. But if one thing is wrong, it's more than obvious things gonna go down south some day.

Answer (score 1):

Try 2 things to start:

**(1) Repair Edge.**  Start, Settings, Apps, Installed Apps, scroll down for Microsoft Edge.  3 dots.  Click Modify. and click on Repair. When done, restart and test.

**(2) Run DISM /SFC and test.**

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

Then, if the above two steps fail to resolve the issue, run a Windows 11 Repair Install.

**(3) Windows 11 Repair Install.**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download. Run the download (need a USB Key), and run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything. Start with Keep Everything.

If a Repair Install does not work (Windows User Profile or other Operating System damage) then the most practical solution is to back everything up and Reinstall Windows fresh

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay - Have you followed my answer?  What happens?

Comment: First two steps didn't work. Strange thing is when i open the browser in incognito mode, i am able to close it normally. Third step needs to be taken. I replied earlier, may be the response was not saved.

Comment: Also, I am not able to follow your third point. You mean to create windows 11 installation media for fresh install, right?

Comment: If the first two steps did not work and you cannot do a Repair, then yes, back up, and use the Windows 11 installation media to do a fresh install.